# Cron job isn't working (or at least logging to the file it should be)

Tags: shell-script, scripting, cron

Cron job is setup as:

```
*/15  * * * * speedtest >> /home/pi/speedtest.log
```

The `speedtest` script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
speedtest-cli --csv >> /home/pi/speedtest.log
```

That uses Speedtest-CLI. The job is executing on time, but all I get is cron output that looks like:

```
Jul 19 08:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[29275]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 19 08:30:01 raspberrypi CRON[29378]: (pi) CMD (speedtest >> /home/pi/speedtest.log)
Jul 19 08:30:01 raspberrypi CRON[29377]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jul 19 08:45:01 raspberrypi CRON[29430]: (pi) CMD (speedtest >> /home/pi/speedtest.log)
Jul 19 08:45:01 raspberrypi CRON[29429]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jul 19 09:00:01 raspberrypi CRON[29608]: (pi) CMD (speedtest >> /home/pi/speedtest.log)
Jul 19 09:00:01 raspberrypi CRON[29607]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jul 19 09:15:01 raspberrypi CRON[29791]: (pi) CMD (speedtest >> /home/pi/speedtest.log)
Jul 19 09:15:01 raspberrypi CRON[29790]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

But I don't see the speedtest.log getting updated. What is going on?

Comment: Where is the script located? If it's not in the `PATH` cron uses, it won't find it. Since you don't have a working email system, you won't see any output that comes from the job, e.g. error messages... There probably would be some output in this case, since cron complains about not having an MTA. It wouldn't need to go that far if there wasn't any output.

Comment: Could also ask what happens if you remove the `/home/pi/speedtest.log` file and let the cron job run. If it appears, then the cron job as such runs, meaning that cron starts the shell that runs that `speedtest >> /home/pi/speedtest.log`, and that shell succeeds in doing that redirection. If that works, you could change the job to `speedtest >> /home/pi/speedtest.log 2>>/home/pi/error.log`, since, well, if your email doesn't work, any errors won't be available there so might as well put them in a file.

Comment: The job is definitely producing error output. Cron then has to discard it as there's nothing else it can do (`No MTA installed, discarding output`)

Comment: Having both the crontab entry *and* the script redirect output to the same file will create an access conflict, where one may write over the other's output (effectively deleting it). Do the redirect *once*, or have them redirect to different files to avoid the conflict. And (as ilkkachu said) redirect errors somewhere too so you can see what's going wrong. It's better to redirect errors in the crontab entry, so it'll catch errors before the script starts running.

Comment: `cron` mails the STDOUT/STDERR streams from your job to you. It tried, but couldn't find a Mail Transfer Agent (MTA).

Comment: @waltinator  Not when the cron log complains there is no Mail Transfer Agent installed.

Comment: Don't let `cron` see your `STDOUT` or `STDERR` streams and `cron` won't try to find an MTA to mail them through. That's one of many reasons  why I recommend wrapping in a `bash` script. Redirection is easier, no need to contort into a 1-liner,

Answer (score 0):

Jobs run through `cron`, or `systemd` startup scripts aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. `systemd` startup scripts are run as `root`. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== id ===";id;echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.